# How to write a rviz plugin

Tags: ros, rviz, rviz-plugins

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi ros answers,

I was wondering about how to add plugins to rviz. I read on the wiki that it was not documented on purpose as there is no stable API. But i would like to take a look at how it is done. Where should I start ?
Thank you.

Guido

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9764/how-to-write-a-rviz-plugin/) by [Guido](https://answers.ros.org/users/279/guido/) on ROS Answers with karma: 514 on 2011-04-18

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There's not a released API at the moment.  For a discussion in the future, I suggest following up on this [ros-developers posting](https://code.ros.org/lurker/message/20110426.172953.7631dbee.en.html)

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-05-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Guido](https://answers.ros.org/users/279/guido/) on 2011-05-08**:
Thanks. I will follow this with interest.